# If I select the check box called "select all", it must checked all check boxes appeared in the below screen

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

[image]

In my case I have created a property file and kept in my Jenkins master machine. and in Jenkins job configuration I have selected "Extended Choice Parameter" and here I have pasted the path of that property file and property key value also. after when I clicked on build with parameter option I am getting above screen. Here If I select the check box called "select all", it must checked all check boxes appeared in the below/above screen. It would be appreciated if any one can help me.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Have you tried Active choices plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the parameter screen.
jenkins parameters are post-processed. This screen is not executing code it is just displaying previously evaluated code.

An option is to change it to

```
MyChoice:
All
A
B
C
```

Then in your pipeline, you can (if all is selected) action all three choices appropriately.

It is not possible to have parameter dynamically change another in Jenkins.

Comment: That's correct. The parameters screen cannot dynamically perform any actions based on a prior parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using 1 Active Choice Parameter and 1 Active Choice Reactive Parameter. Active Choice Reactive Parameter reacts to the option selected in Active Choice Parameter. Create a checkbox with the name "Select all" in it and when checked, the options in Active Choice Reactive Parameter will select all options in it in real-time. I have written code for this in the below answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67749746/10779115

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to provide an option to select multiple parameters and if you chose "Select All", it should pick everything.

Why can't you try "Custom Checkbox Parameter"

https://plugins.jenkins.io/custom-checkbox-parameter/