# How do I get the select all button in Jenkins.?

Tags: jenkins

How do I get the select all button in Jenkins. There is no select all button seen in extended choice. If u choose a product there are multiple service
So instead of choosing selected one. I wan to choose all option. How can I get the select all option in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Active Choices Parameter(name=Selection)with 2 radio button options:

1. Select all
2. Clear all

Use groovy script:

```
return[
'Select all:selected',
'Clear all'
]
```

For your products, you can now use Active Choice Reactive Parameter with checkboxes. Your selection in Active Choice Parameter will have a reaction in this parameter.

Use groovy script:

```
import hudson.model.*
def result = [prod1,prod2,prod3];
def returnValue = [];
if(Selection.equals("Select all"))
{
   result.each{prod->
   returnValue<<prod+":selected";
   }
   return returnValue;
}
else if(Selection.equals("Clear all"))
{
   return result;
}
```

Do not forget to set the Referenced parameter in Active Choice Reactive Parameter as "Selection" which is the Active Choice Parameter.